# How to generate changes between two javadoc versions

Tags: java, html, documentation, javadoc, doc

I have java source code for which generated a javadocs using below

```
javadoc -d old_javadoc -sourcepath /path/to/old_source_folder -subpackages my.package.name
```

Then made some changes to code, like: added few classes and methods, removed some methods etc..
Now generated agin updated javadoc with below.

```
javadoc -d updated_javadoc -sourcepath /path/to/updated_source_folder -subpackages my.package.name
```

Now need to generate All changes html file which shows what are the changes Between old javadoc and updated javadoc?
**Note: Jdk17 environment**